# Making this SQL in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I try make this SQL in My Sequelize controller, but I don't know, that data_time looks only < 30 days.

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM bankapplication_transactions
WHERE id_sender = 1
OR id_recipient = 1
AND data_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
ORDER BY data_time DESC
```

Sequelize controller:

```
Transaction.findAll({
              where: db.Sequelize.and(
                {
                  data_time: moment().add(-30, 'days'), // this is ok?
                },
                db.Sequelize.or(
                  { id_sender: 1 },
                  { id_recipient: 1 },
                ),
              ),

              order: ['data_time', 'DESC'],
            }).then(transaction_history => {
              if (transaction_history) {
                console.log('transaction_history', transaction_history);
              }
            });
```

Comment: can you post the SQL after run code ? is the `or` condition working correctly ? so sql only search `data_time <= 2019-01-16` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var today, afterMonth = new Date();
afterMonth.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 1);
```

...

```
where: db.Sequelize.and(
            {
              data_time:  $between: [today , afterMonth ]
            },
```